# Subordinate conjunction "Just as": different meaning depending on the position in the sentence?

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis, phrase-order, focusing-adverbs

I was searching for sentences with **just as** in the meaning of *"in the same way as"*.
It seems to me that subordinate sentences with **just as** can either describe 'the way' something is being done (a), or providing a comparison with a 'similar situation' (b):
(a) *He's signing his name just as he's always done it.* (https://www.dictionary.com/browse/just-as)
(b) *Just as an adjective can describe a noun, an adverb can describe a verb.*

The above examples, as I see it, show that **just as** can "focus" on different aspects of a situation. What would be the correct explanation of the difference?

Also, it seems that in the case of (a), the sentence with **just as** can't proceed the main one (**'Just as he's always done it, he's signing his name.*') unless we mean not *the way he signs his name* but have some specific context (like referring to the fact that 'he has signed his name before, he is signing his name at this moment, as well.')
Whereas (b) seems to allow such a modification without changing the meaning: 
(c) ?*An adverb can describe a verb, just as an adjective can describe a noun.*

How can it be explained? Would it be true to say that when at the beginning of the sentence subordinate sentences with **just as** can modify **how** smth is done but not compare two different situations? And when used *after* the main sentence it can have both meanings?

Other examples are:
(d) comparison of situations:
*Just as Jack abandoned his family for an adventure, John left his wife and went to sea.*
*John left his wife and went to sea, just as Jack abandoned his family for an adventure.*
(e) in the same way as:
*I wrote my essay with five paragraphs just as my professor told me to do in the instructions. (https://www.myenglishteacher.eu/blog/subordinating-conjunctions/)*
*?Just as my professor told me to do in the instructions I wrote my essay with five paragraphs.*

I would be very grateful for any information on this matter.

Comment: Merriam-Webster seems to support the idea that "just as" at the start of a sentence means "in the same way as" and in the middle means "to the same degree as". That seems a good rule of thumb, but it's possible it may be broken occasionally. Is there a specific sentence you're interested in or want to know if it's correct? https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/just%20as

Comment: For completeness, there is a question on "just as" in English Language Learners, but it's not very relevant: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/112877/usage-of-just-as

Comment: The examples given in Merriam-Webster for 'to an equal degree as' have "just as" as an adverb as far as I understand: it is followed by an adjective there.

I am referring to when it is used for two sentences, and I am wondering if there is any explanation (maybe in the syntax domain), if there are actually two meanings of "just as" in such a function (one referring to "the way smth is done", the other is comparing two situations).